# How to read data from nested json file with Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have been trying all day to read data from a json file like below with Qt but can't find a way to do it properly. I tried many things but could not get it right. Can someone help me how to get this correctly?

```
{
    "RawData": {
        "Sensors": {
            "Channel1" : "10",
            "Channel2" : "22",
            "Channel3" : "3",
            "Channel4" : "48",
            "Channel5" : "1",
            "Channel6" : "8",
            "Channel7" : "16",
            "Channel8" : "44"
        }
    }
}
```

for now my code looks something like this, though i tried many things with different manners.

```
QFile jsonCfg("config.json");
if (!jsonCfg.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qWarning("Couldn't open json config file.");
    return false;
}
QByteArray saveData = jsonCfg.readAll();
QJsonDocument loadDoc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(saveData));
QJsonObject config = loadDoc.object();
QVariantMap root_map = config.toVariantMap();
QVariantMap raw = root_map["RawData"].toMap();
QVariantMap sensor = raw["Sensors"].toMap();
qDebug() << "channel 1" << sensor["Channel1"].toDouble();
```

Comment: In Json you have "Sensors" but in code you're looking for "Sensor".

Comment: You are right thanks. I had just renamed the fields before pasting here. But this is still not working.

Comment: Ok I found out that the file was not opened and for some reason, the warning was not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use QJsonDocument and QJsonObject just like:

```
QJsonParseError jsonErr;
QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonStr,&jsonErr);
if(jsonErr.error == QJsonParseError::NoError)
{
    QJsonObject myJsonObject = jsonDoc.object();
    if(myJsonObject["RawData"].isObject())
    {
        //do somethine your want;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is still not giving me any hint how to get "Channel1" field.